# My cypress always stops running. Does anyone know why?

Tags: cypress

My cypress starts working fine. I am trying a simple cy.visit() test. However, it breaks all the time. Has anyone had this problem? Sometimes, it just keeps loading and loading and breaks.

[image of cypress loading and breaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvhf3.png)

I thought it could be a problem with the version. I tried installing an older version and deleting the whole folder of cypress when uninstalling it, but it has not worked.

Comment: have you checked your memory?

Comment: My storage is a bit full, so is the RAM. I am gonna try to clean my PC a little and see what happens.

Comment: it is consuming much of my cpu actually, I think this is causing the problem.

Comment: it was getting 60% of my CPU just to make a cy.visit()